# Scoring Word Frequency in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, select, syntax-error, aggregate-functions

I'm working with a one-table database that is composed of 2 columns: an integer wordID, and the varchar word. The table is several thousand lines long and was created by reading a lot of text in programatically and splitting on a space, then ucasing the individual words and inserting them into a database. The goal is to use this dictionary in order to read full-text blog posts, tweets, other text content and score them for relevance.

What I'd like to do is compute the count of each word (which I have working by itself) as well as the "score" of each word - that is to say, a word mush show up a minimum number of times in the data set to have a score, and the score is the inverse of the frequency of the word, on a scale of 1-10. The thought is that the more often a word comes up, the less valuable it'll be in my text-search later down the line. However it must appear a minimum number of times in order to be useful as well, because a one-off probably was a typo.

Here's my select statement and attempt to score word frequencies at the same time as generating a count.

```
  select word, 
  count(word), 
  10*(((max(count(word))+1) - count(word))/(max(count(word))))
  from dictwords where length(word)>3 group by word having count(word)>35 
  order by count(word) desc;
```

The error returned by mysql is "Invalid use of group function." Error 1111.

Is it possible to do this sort of thing in one statement in mySQL? Or should I break up the counting and scoring into two queries by doing a select into and feed my result table into a place holder table then attempt to score it?

Comment: MAX(COUNT is the problem. For more/better help, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: I think his length(word)>3 is also wrong. That he means count(word)>3

Comment: He shoud change count(word) in SELECT word, count(word) to: SELECT word, count(word) as frequency. He could then replace all the count(word) references with frequency. Much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in a single query as you are trying to find the number of times the most common word occurs (I think). This worked for me on a test data set:

```
# get the number of times the most common word occurs
select @maxCount := count(word)
from temp 
where length(word)>3 
group by word 
having count(word)>10
order by count(word) desc
limit 1;

# now use that max value to calculate a score
select 
    word, 
    count(word) as wordCount,
    @maxCount as maxWordCount,
    10*(((@maxCount+1) - count(word))/(@maxCount)) as score
from temp 
where length(word)>3 
group by word 
having wordCount>10
order by wordCount desc;
```

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9919/1) if you want to see if I have it correct.

Comment: This is fairly similar to the response that I got from playing around with the code - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
  drop table if exists wordcount;

  create table wordcount(
   word varchar(50) primary key,
   wc   int     not null
  );

  insert into wordcount (word, wc)
  select word, count(word)
  from dictwords 
  where length(word)>3 
  group by word 
  having count(word)>35 
  order by count(word) desc;


  drop table if exists wordscore;
  create table wordscore(
  word  varchar(50) primary key,
  score int     not null);

  insert into wordscore (word, score)
  select word, (1-(10*(((max(wc)+1) - wc)/(max(wc)))))*10
  from wordcount 
  group by word;
```

had to create a table in passing here - but I got it to go. Since I only looked at words with a count of 35 instances or more in the raw data, we get a score of like 7-10 in this result set.